# JMeter Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a JMeter test which works in GUI-Mode but when i try to run it in NonGui-Mode i get this error:

```
WARNING: package sun.awt.X11 not in java.desktop
Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException: ModuleController:[Mod] Login has no selected Controller (did you rename some element in the path to target controller?), test was shutdown as a consequence
An error occurred: Error in NonGUIDriver ModuleController:[Mod] Login has no selected Controller (did you rename some element in the path to target controller?), test was shutdown as a consequence
```

JMeter version: 5.4.1

Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_292"

Comment: Do you have (Module Controllers)[https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller] in the test ? If yes please ensure that they are attached to the target test fragments. The mapping is lost when you when you rename the items. `A fragment name is made up of the Controller name and all its parent names`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Turns out i had a section in my test where the Module Controller was not attached to the target test fragments. (I didn´t wirte the test myself). Removed this section and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is self-explanatory:

1. You have a [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) somewhere in your Test Plan
2. The Module Controller doesn't refer to any [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)

So you just need to find the problematic Module Controller and choose which Test Fragment you want to execute at this place:

[image]

As you can see on attempt to run the test containing the Module Controller not connected to any Test Fragment I'm getting the same error as you do, however when I explicitly point the Module Controller to the Test Fragment - the underlying Sampler gets executed

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but i think you get my Problem wrong the test runs perfectly fine when i start it in GUI-Mode. However, I want to run the jmeter test on a ubuntu server where I can only use the command line. When i start the test in non-gui-mode i get this error, locally and on the server.

Comment: Turns out i was wrong. Fixed my error thank you :)